# Git autocompletions raises the error "bash: [: -lt: unary operator expected"

Tags: bash, scripts, git, bashrc, auto-completion

In a **Ubuntu 21.10** (new computer with setup)
with git version **2.32.0**
and bash version **5.1.8**(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

I can't use alias for `git checkout` because it generates the error `bash: [: -lt: unary operator expected`.

So, in my `.bashrc` i have

```sh
alias gitc="git checkout"
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

and then

```sh
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
__git_complete gitc _git_checkout
```

And when I try to change to "develop" branch typing "gitc deve" + tab => I get the mentioned error

All the posts I found regarding this error are very old, actually the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git` I can see the comment:

> # Compatible with bash 3.2.57.

Does anybody have solved this issue?

Thanks

------ Edited at CPH`s request:

I had to change the funtion in line 3512, from

```
__git_func_wrap ()
{
    local cur words cword prev
    ...
```

to

```
__git_func_wrap ()
{
    local cur words cword prev __git_cmd_idx=1
    ...
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion?

Comment: Sure,... well what I've done is exactly what the associated question says, anyway I edit my question

Comment: Ahh, glad you found your answer!